# Ccoenraets backbone-cellar example with multiple tables (backbone.js / SLIM framework)

Tags: backbone.js, slim-lang

What I am trying to accomplish is getting ccoenraets backbone-cellar example to work with multiple tables in the cellar database.

What I have tried so far by altering 'part-1' of the example:

1. I altered the database: I duplicated the existing 'wine' table to
   'winedetail'. Then I deleted all the columns in 'wine' exept for id
   and name.
2. I've changed the functions in index.php to:

   ```
   function getWines() {

   $sql = "select name,id FROM wine ORDER BY name";
   try {
       $db = getConnection();
       $stmt = $db->query($sql);  
       $wines = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
       $db = null;
       // echo '{"wine": ' . json_encode($wines) . '}';
       echo json_encode($wines);
   } catch(PDOException $e) {
       echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
   }
   }

   function getWine($id) {

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM winedetail WHERE id=:id";
   try {
       $db = getConnection();
       $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  
       $stmt->bindParam("id", $id);
       $stmt->execute();
       $wine = $stmt->fetchObject();  
       $db = null;
       echo json_encode($wine); 
   } catch(PDOException $e) {
       echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
   }
   }
   ```

The error I'm getting in chome console :

Uncaught ReferenceError: grapes is not defined

I have not altered the index.html and main.js. For reference I will post them here as well:

**main.js**

```
// Models
window.Wine = Backbone.Model.extend();

window.WineCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:Wine,
    url:"../api/wines"
});



window.WineListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName:'ul',

    initialize:function () {
        this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
    },

    render:function (eventName) {
        _.each(this.model.models, function (wine) {
            $(this.el).append(new WineListItemView({model:wine}).render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    }

});


// Views
window.WineListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName:"li",

    template:_.template($('#tpl-wine-list-item').html()),

    render:function (eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }

});

window.WineView = Backbone.View.extend({

    template:_.template($('#tpl-wine-details').html()),

    render:function (eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }

});


// Router
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes:{
        "":"list",
        "wines/:id":"wineDetails"
    },

    list:function () {
        this.wineList = new WineCollection();
        this.wineListView = new WineListView({model:this.wineList});
        this.wineList.fetch();
        $('#sidebar').html(this.wineListView.render().el);
    },

    wineDetails:function (id) {
        this.wine = this.wineList.get(id);
        this.wineView = new WineView({model:this.wine});
        $('#content').html(this.wineView.render().el);
    }
});

var app = new AppRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Backbone Cellar</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="header"><span class="title">Backbone Cellar</span></div>

<div id="sidebar"></div>

<div id="content">
<h2>Welcome to Backbone Cellar</h2>
<p>
This is a sample application part of of three-part tutorial showing how to build a CRUD application with Backbone.js.
</p>
</div>

<!-- Templates -->
<script type="text/template" id="tpl-wine-list-item">
    <a href='#wines/<%= id %>'><%= name %></a>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="tpl-wine-details">
    <div class="form-left-col">
        <label>Id:</label>
        <input type="text" id="wineId" name="id" value="<%= id %>" disabled />
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<%= name %>" required/>
        <label>Grapes:</label>
        <input type="text" id="grapes" name="grapes" value="<%= grapes %>"/>
        <label>Country:</label>
        <input type="text" id="country" name="country" value="<%= country %>"/>
        <label>Region:</label>
        <input type="text" id="region" name="region"  value="<%= region %>"/>
        <label>Year:</label>
        <input type="text" id="year" name="year"  value="<%= year %>"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-right-col">
        <img height="300" src="../pics/<%= picture %>"/>
        <label>Notes:</label>
        <textarea id="description" name="description"><%= description %></textarea>
    </div>
</script>

<!-- JavaScript -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/backbone-min.js"></script>   
<script src="js/main.js"></script>   

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: All right you are trying to start off crom this tutorial but try to make something of your own from it. fine, but just for the reference, this is the tutorial that is the base of the above app: https://github.com/ccoenraets/backbone-cellar

Comment: I think you should use two different models to represent two different data sets. You fetch() all the data from  Wines (id, name) and the model assumes it has all the data needed. That you try to render you template for the wineDetails. Collections just provides a model, that was retrieved with fetch() => id, name. It does not make a second request to get the rest of you data from the second table (it assumes it has all the data already). The template then tries renders the model.grapes and throws an error.

You should create a separate model for the Detailed data.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
wineDetails:function (id) {
    var wine = this.wineList.get(id);
    wine.fetch({
      success: function(){
        console.log(wine);
        var wineView = new WineView({model: wine});
        $('#content').html(wineView.render().el);
      }
    });
}
```

Make sure that the model printed int he console has a `grapes` value. Doing the above makes the view wait until the model has been fetched before trying to display it. If the code above works, it means that either:

- when you're fetching the collection, you're missing the `grapes` value on your models
- you're not waiting for the collection to be fetched before displaying the wine details

Note also that it looks like if a user goes directly to url "wines/1" your app will crash, becasue there's no collection instance.